# use "svn delete --force" on unversioned copies, how to get my deleted files back

Tags: svn

I'm using SVN 1.4.2 from command line. I created a new folder called test, and this is my folder structure:

```
.
|-- figures_index.aux
|-- figures_index.dvi
|-- figures_index.log
|-- figures_index.lyx
|-- figures_index.pdf
|-- figures_index.ps
|-- figures_index.tex
|-- main.lyx
|-- test
`-- thesisMain.tex

1 directory, 9 files
```

All files apart from the new created folder test are under version control. I used the following command

```
$ svn del --force thesis_latex/trunk/main/test
```

Is there anyway to get the test file back? The svn revert didn't work.

Comment: "The svn revert didn't work." That's the crux. It does work, since this is one of the main reasons why you have a VCS. Specify what you tried and what went wrong, then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Why should it work if the folder wasn't under version control? These were normal files, svn deleted them for you since you `--force`d it to. Svn won't help you, get undelete or some such utility.

Comment: @Anton: Sorry, I missed the part where Dean wrote "All files apart from the new created folder test are under version control". Well, you're certainly right. That's it then. No way to get that back except for OS-specific undelete utilities - if there are any for that OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try merging from the revision where files exist:

```
svn merge -rPREV:HEAD URL PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description the file was never in SVN.
The SVN client deleted the file from the filesystem, it doesn't make a backup for you of unversioned files.

You need to look to your filesystem/backups for recovery of the file.
Windows - recycle bin might have it depends on how your client performed the deletion,
*nux - you'd be lucky to be using an FS with undo.